# How do I position a HTML element statically relative to another element?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I've this HTML:

```
<div id="article">
 <div id="article-text">...</div>
 <div id="slogan">Best Article Is Best</div>
</div>
```

How do I position `#slogan` always at `top: 100` within `#article`?

I've tried setting absolute and relative position on `#slogan` and using `top: 100` but if article text is bigger than 100px then `#slogan` will be pushed down.

Is there a way to position an element absolutely (or is it statically?) relative to its parent, no matter what content parent has?

Comment: Also include the actual CSS currently in play; in standard stylesheet format.

Comment: Absolute position with `top: 100px` shouldn't be pushed down by `#article-text`.

Comment: Believe or not it gets pushed down. I will create an example paste bin. `#article-text` is a inline-block actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#article{
    position: relative;
}
#slogan{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thx it started working by itself after I rebooted my Windows 98 laptop.